# preventDefault() won't stop the page from refreshing

Tags: html, ajax, flask

So, a bit of background for starters.

I'm following the link below to do a simple post request.

https://codehandbook.org/python-flask-jquery-ajax-post/

I have done everything as it says and the page -surprisingly- works. The only problem is that it still keeps refreshing the page whenever I press "submit" even with the `preventDefault()` function in it.
It is supposed to do some stuff in Flask with the variables I give it in the HTML below and before I get to that I would like to get rid of this little annoyance.

Here's my HTML:

```
<fieldset>
<form>
    Yrityksen nimi: <input name="Yrityksennimi" type="text" id="YN"  placeHolder="yritys" ></input><br>
    Ennustettu kasvu: <input name="Ennustettukasvu" type="number" min="1" max="2" step="0.001" value="1" id="kasvu"><br>
    Diskonttokorko: <input name="Diskonttokorko" type="number" min="0" max="1" step="0.001" value="0" id="DK"><br>
    BKT: <input name="BKT" type="number" min="0" max="1" step="0.001" value="0" id="BK"><br>
    Osakkeiden yhteenlaskettu määrä: <input name="Osakkeidenyhteenlaskettumaara" type="number" min="0" max="1000000000000000000000000" step="1" value="0" id="OM"><br>
    Vapaa kassavirta: <input name="Vapaakassavirta" type="number" min="0" max="1000000000000000000000000" step="0.1" value="0" id="KV"><br>
    Mittausajan pituus: <input name="Mittausajanpituus" type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" id="MP"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"></input>
</form>
</fieldset>
```

Here's the Flask:

```
@app.route('/DCF-calculator', methods =['POST'])

def DCFcalc():

    n = request.form['Yrityksennimi'];
    g = request.form['Ennustettukasvu'];
    dr = request.form['Diskonttokorko'];
    gdp = request.form['BKT'];
    s = request.form['Osakkeidenyhteenlaskettumaara'];
    f = request.form['Vapaakassavirta'];
    v = request.form['Mittausajanpituus'];
return json.dumps({'status': 'OK', 'YN':n, 'kasvu':g, 'DK':dr, 'BK':gdp,'OM':s,'KV':f,'MP':c});
```

And finally the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('submit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var YN = $('#YN').val();
        var kasvu = $('#kasvu').val();
        var DK = $('#DK').val();
        var BK = $('#BKT').val();
        var OM = $('#OM').val();
        var KV = $('#KV').val();
        var MP = $('#MP').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/DCF-calculator',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` in such cases

Or give id to form and use

```
 $("#formid"). submit (function (e){e.preventDefault(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

as long as you use "submit" type, the form still submit and refresh the page. Change

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"></input>
```

to

```
<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit"></input>
```

will solve your problem

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

change your code to catch **submit** event of the form and use **preventDefault** and **return false**

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     // code

     return false;
});
```

Comment: The `return false;` is unnecessary. The event just need to be prevented from the `form` and not the `submit` button.

Answer (score 0):

You are not binding the click event to the button, this `$('submit')` doesn't bind to the submit button, use the id of the submit button `$(#submit)`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submit').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var YN = $('#YN').val();
            var kasvu = $('#kasvu').val();
            var DK = $('#DK').val();
            var BK = $('#BKT').val();
            var OM = $('#OM').val();
            var KV = $('#KV').val();
            var MP = $('#MP').val();
            //uncomment this lines
            // $.ajax({
            //     url: '/DCF-calculator',
            //     data: $('form').serialize(),
            //     type: 'POST',
            //     success: function (response) {
            //         console.log(response);
            //     },
            //     error: function (error) {
            //         console.log(error);
            //     }
            // });
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    Yrityksen nimi: <input name="Yrityksennimi" type="text" id="YN" placeHolder="yritys"></input><br>
    Ennustettu kasvu: <input name="Ennustettukasvu" type="number" min="1" max="2" step="0.001" value="1" id="kasvu"><br>
    Diskonttokorko: <input name="Diskonttokorko" type="number" min="0" max="1" step="0.001" value="0" id="DK"><br>
    BKT: <input name="BKT" type="number" min="0" max="1" step="0.001" value="0" id="BK"><br>
    Osakkeiden yhteenlaskettu määrä: <input name="Osakkeidenyhteenlaskettumaara" type="number" min="0"
                                            max="1000000000000000000000000" step="1" value="0" id="OM"><br>
    Vapaa kassavirta: <input name="Vapaakassavirta" type="number" min="0" max="1000000000000000000000000" step="0.1"
                             value="0" id="KV"><br>
    Mittausajan pituus: <input name="Mittausajanpituus" type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" id="MP"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: I gave the form the "values" and for the submit button "submit" id. and there was no difference

Comment: i also changed the ('#submit') to (#submit) and nothing changed. also, the send button seems to become unnecessary since when i change the value of one of the inputs, it comes out as successful: "127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2017 11:02:32] "POST /DCF-calculator HTTP/1.1" 200 -
"

Comment: @jormauotinen  if you are using the same form as above, it should work, use `('#submit')` as this is the id of your submit button.